# Not Giving a proper output for every test case

Tags: arrays

Given an array of  integers print each element in reverse order as a single line of space-separated integers.
Input Format

Output Format

Print all  integers in  in reverse order as a single line of space-separated integers.

Sample Input

```
4

1 4 3 2
```

Sample Output

```
2 3 4 1
```

Here's my Code

```
int main()

{


int n;


int a[n];

    cin >>n;

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       cin>>a[i]; 
    }

    for (int i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what's your question? What debugging have you done?

Comment: when n= 100 and all the elements are inserted, the output gives the segmentation fault error. But for smaller values of n, such as 4 or 5, the output is as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can not allocate an static array with a variable size meaning the expression a[n] is not acceptable since in the compile time the variable "n" is not determined. If this question have a limit for "n" - for example n < 1000 - then replace the expression with `int a[1000] ;`. If it doesn't , replace it with `int* a = new int[n] ;`. It is called dynamic allocation , you can search it to find out how amazing it is ;)

Comment: Thanks for this, initially, my code worked for 3 out of the 9 test cases. Now it works for 7 out of the 9 test cases after i dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: *sigh* but now 2 of the test cases which have n as 1000 give the wrong answer apparantly

Comment: And now, instead of dynamically allocating memory, i've declared a[1000] and this clears all the test cases.
I really do wonder how both of these methods are different from one another.

Comment: can you send the link to the question ?

Comment: I think i found out why you got a wrong answer . Look , when you dynamically allocate memory , you need to delete it after you used your memory , to free up the memory

Comment: Thank you. I'm assuming you already tried freeing the allocated memory and cleared all 9 test cases.